# How to display Font Awesome logos within an image

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, font-awesome

So im following this Youtube video on how to build a website in HTML & CSS https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=99vHH_6F0Ko&t=3071s&ab_channel=EasyTutorials im around 50 minutes in.

Im stumped on how to make my font-awesome logos appear within my image, like the video. I dont know if its the image size or what!?!
im trying to upload a picture of Elon Musk that is 360x540px if that matters.

Problem: I think the best example would be in the video at 51:00-51:15 minutes in. But when I use that exact code on MY website, the font awesome box of logos appears UNDER the image which is no good. I would like the Font Awesome Logos to appear within the image like the video.

Im having a couple troubles with this tutorial... im a super noob.
On my website im trying to create a row of 4 team member images. When I try to add more profile pics it just goes vertically down the document and all the Logos bunch up at the bottom,not horizontally like it shows in the video. I need professional help plz xD

```css
#team {
  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  color: #555;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  color: #555 !important;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

h1::after {
  content: '';
  background: #007bff;
  display: block;
  height: 3px;
  width: 170px;
  margin: 20px auto 5px;

}
.profile-pic {
  margin-top: 25px;
}

.profile-pic .img-box {
  opacity: 1;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  }

  .profile-pic .img-box img {
    filter: grayscale(1);
  }

  .profile-pic .img-box img:hover {
    filter: grayscale(0);
    cursor: pointer;

  }

 .profile-pic h2 {
   font-size: 22px;
   font-weight: bold;
   margin-top: 15px;
   color: #007bff !important;
 }

 .profile-pic h3 {
   font-size: 15px;
   font-weight: bold;
   margin-top: 15px;

 }

 #team .fa {
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  color: #007bff !important;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 4px;
  border-radius: 50%;

}

.img-box ul {
  padding: 15px 0;
   position: absolute;
   z-index: 2;
   bottom: 0;
   left: 50%;
   transform: translateX(-50%);

}
```

```html
 <head>
<title>Business Website</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet"
href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"

  script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</script><script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<section id="team">
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Our Team</h1>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3 profile-pic text-center">
        <div class="img-box">
          <img src="images/teampic.png" class="img-fluid">
          <ul>
            <a href="#"><li><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></li></a>
              <a href="#"><li><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></li></a>
                <a href="#"><li><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></li></a>
            </ul>
            <div>
              <h2>Elon Musk</h2>
              <h3>Founder/CEO</h3>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
            consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
          </div>
       </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</section>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides putting it under the `img` attribute, you can actually put it under `div` and set the `background-image` from the CSS. For the horizontal ul list, you only need to make the `li` elements have the display `inline` or `inline-block`.

```css
.img-box {
   background-image: url('Your Image URL here');
}

.img-box ul li {
   display: 'inline-block';
}
```

Also in my opinion, there is better if the `ul` elements have direct children `li` instead of `a`, so I changed it to :

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a></li>
</ul>
```

Here is the full code snippet:

```css
#team {
  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  color: #555;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  color: #555 !important;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

h1::after {
  content: '';
  background: #007bff;
  display: block;
  height: 3px;
  width: 170px;
  margin: 20px auto 5px;

}
.profile-pic {
  margin-top: 25px;
}

.profile-pic .img-box {
  opacity: 1;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  }

  .profile-pic .img-box img {
    filter: grayscale(1);
  }

  .profile-pic .img-box img:hover {
    filter: grayscale(0);
    cursor: pointer;

  }

 .profile-pic h2 {
   font-size: 22px;
   font-weight: bold;
   margin-top: 15px;
   color: #007bff !important;
 }

 .profile-pic h3 {
   font-size: 15px;
   font-weight: bold;
   margin-top: 15px;

 }

 #team .fa {
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  color: #007bff !important;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 4px;
  border-radius: 50%;

}

.img-box {
  background-image: url("https://img.freepik.com/free-vector/white-minimal-background_1393-354.jpg?size=626&ext=jpg");
}

.img-box ul {
  padding: 15px 0;
   position: relative;
   z-index: 2;
   bottom: 0;
   left: 50%;
   transform: translateX(-50%);
}


.img-box ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<head>
<title>Business Website</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet"
href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"

  script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</script><script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<section id="team">
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Our Team</h1>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3 profile-pic text-center">
        <div class="img-box">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a></li>
            </ul>
            <div>
              <h2>Elon Musk</h2>
              <h3>Founder/CEO</h3>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
            consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
          </div>
       </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</section>
</body>
```

Comment: How can I now put that img-box within the image? It displays the logos under the image.

Comment: Hi, sorry for late response, I just recently changed the snippet, you can check it and wonder if it can satisfy your need.